# C# Unit Testing validate if data input is being deserialized

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, serialization

How can I unit test if my JSON input is being deserialized? I am trying to deserialize a JSON input, calculate and then serialize. But I don't know how to check if my input is being deserialized. So I am writing unit test to validate.

**NOTE:** AlphaCalcParam ParseParameter is a private method. This is where I am getting an error.

**Unit Test**

```
   [TestMethod()]
            public void ParseParameterTest()
            {
                Algo.Alpha.AlphaCalculator calc = new Alpha.AlphaCalculator();

                string test_input = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\case\Alpha Example Input.json");
                string expected = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\case\Alpha Example DOutput.json");
                string res = calc.AlphaCalcParam(test_input);

                res == expected
                Assert.Fail();
            }
```

**Logic**

```
 public string Calculation(string json_param)
        {
            try
            {
                AlphaCalcParam param = ParseParameter(json_param);
                AlphaCalcResults result = CalculateAlpha(param);

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Failed in Alpha Calculation!. " + e.Message;
            }
        }

...some more code.. below is what i want to test...

 private AlphaCalcParam ParseParameter(string json_param)
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlphaCalcParam>(json_param);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("The input json string format is wrong for Alpha Calculation!. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seriously, don't understand with all the downvotes. New to C#. Trying to learn. Help me improve. That is what I thought stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test right now is always Asserting to a failure. What you need to do is test the expected value of res.

```
 [TestMethod()]
        public void ParseParameterTest()
        {
            Algo.Alpha.AlphaCalculator calc = new Alpha.AlphaCalculator();

            string test_input = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\case\Alpha Example Input.json");
            string expected = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\case\Alpha Example DOutput.json");
            string res = calc.AlphaCalcParam(test_input);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }
```

If res isn't the expected value, the unit test will fail.

Take a look at the [Assert Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) documenation for all available methods of testing.

Comment: @dpimenete thanks but AlphaCalcParam is a private method.

Comment: Well the logic of unit testing is what you want. For testing you may have to make the AlphaCalcParam method internal or public, not private. Otherwise a new accessor function could be used.